# UWA Change PATH connection Database

Tags: sqlite, win-universal-app

good morning I'm considering creating a Universal app windows 10 limited to the classic desktop and mobile app CRUD but I wanted to make sure that both devices were using the same database, I wanted to ask if you can change the connection string and indicate a specific directory in the local network. I wanted to avoid making a WebAPI REST.
This is the path to change:

```
path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is small in size ( < 100kb ), how about you utilize the Roaming Folder ?